# passing byteBuffer as a parameter in point object

Tags: bytebuffer

can you explain to me what does this Code snippet do? I dont understand how the point object got parameters as byteBuffer, and whats the purpose of getInt(4) and getInt(8), why 4 and 8?

```
protected Point getEnd() {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = null;
        try {
            final byte[] page = this.bufferManager.getPage(this.pageSize, new BufferManager.PageAddress(0, this.path1));
            byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(page);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new Point(byteBuffer.getInt(4), byteBuffer.getInt(8));
    }
```

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt(int)

Comment: I did actually read the documentation, is that you answer to my question?